# Rust: casting trait to concrete implementation

Tags: rust

Let's say I want to store elements of different types in `HashMap` but all of them will implement some trait. And I want to be able to retrieve element casted to the right type. The choice of the key allows me to be sure about the type of the element (in the example below type id of the object is a part of the key). How to properly convert found element to `T`?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait MyTrait {
    fn new() -> Self where Self: Sized;

    // Other methods
}

struct MyStruct {
    items: HashMap<(i32, TypeId), Rc<dyn MyTrait>>
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn get<T: MyTrait + 'static>(&mut self, key: i32) -> Rc<T> {
        if let Some(item) = self.items.get(&(key, TypeId::of::<T>())) {
            item.clone() as Rc<T> // !!! Compilation error !!!
        } else {
            let item = Rc::new(T::new());
            self.items.insert((key, TypeId::of::<T>()), item.clone());
            item
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rust is complaining because, on the current stable compiler, you simply can't cast between traits with `as`. You can however cast an `Rc<dyn Any>` to `Rc<T>` with [`downcast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downcast), but it needs to be `Rc<dyn Any>`, not `Rc<dyn MyTrait>`, and it returns a `Result` because (as far as the compiler knows) it might fail. For example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    items: HashMap<(i32, TypeId), Rc<dyn Any>>
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn get<T: MyTrait + 'static>(&mut self, key: i32) -> Rc<T> {
        if let Some(item) = self.items.get(&(key, TypeId::of::<T>())) {
            item.clone().downcast::<T>().unwrap()
        } else {
            // ...
```

The `trait_upcasting` feature on the current nightly compiler allows you to store your values as `Rc<dyn MyTrait>` and upcast to `Rc<dyn Any>` with `as` later:

```
#![feature(trait_upcasting)]

struct MyStruct {
    items: HashMap<(i32, TypeId), Rc<dyn MyTrait>>
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn get<T: MyTrait + 'static>(&mut self, key: i32) -> Rc<T> {
        if let Some(item) = self.items.get(&(key, TypeId::of::<T>())) {
            (item.clone() as Rc<dyn Any>).downcast::<T>().unwrap()
        } else {
            // ...
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow save information that in the map we store not any object, but only implementations of MyTrait, so I can call directly methods of MyTrait when I don't need exact struct?

Comment: @kiv_apple turns out there's a new feature on nightly that would let you do that, I'll edit